# root en css, no se activa para iniciar a diseñar lo de html

Tags: html, css

tengo una pregunta; cuando inicio style de css la etiqueta "root", no se activa, queda como un texto y no se pone de color, para si empezar a dar diseños, sera que falta algun complemento a sublime? o en que estare fallando?, mil gracias por sus respuestas, saludos

Comment: podrías dejar el código?, para así poder ayudarte.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

La forma correcta es **:root**, con dos puntos antepuestos:

```
:root {
  --color: violet;
}
```

Si aún así no funciona, entonces la extensión de tu archivo podría no ser **.css**.
La extensión es: *styles.css*

Si aún así no funciona, ya sería tu editor o la extensión o algo.